# VBA - How does one print just the values into a given cell?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to print just the values of the yahoo function into the 39th cell with the input being from the first column of the sheet. The function returns a single string. Evaluate, .Value, and .Formula don't workout for me. I'm getting multiple errors and syntax errors. Any input would be much appreciated! I'm a newbie at VBA.

```
Sub Button2_Click()
    Dim LastRow As Long

    If Range("A5") <> vbNullString And Range("A6") <> vbNullString Then
        LastRow = Range("A5").End(xlDown).Row
    End If

    With Range("AN5:AN" & LastRow)
        Dim texttmp As String: textmp = Evaluate("yahoo(RC[-39])")


        '.FormulaR1C1 = "=yahoo(RC[-39])"
        '.FormulaR1C1 = "yahoo(MID(RC[-39],1,LEN(RC[-39]))"
        '.Value2 = "=yahoo(RC[-39])"
        '.Value = "yahoo"
        '.Value2 = Evaluate("yahoo(RC[-39])")

    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: How is the `yahoo` function defined?

Comment: `Function yahoo(Symbols As String) As String`

Comment: Is this `yahoo` really an excel formula??? I mean, can you manually put `yahoo` into a cell and get valid result?? Or is it a VBA function??

Comment: vba function, but I thought that was obvious given its name. Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the whole range in one go, fill it with the formula, then overwrite it with the calculated value.

```
With Range("AN5:AN" & LastRow)
    .FormulaR1C1= "=yahoo(RC[-39])"
    .Value = .Value 
End With
```